# Do I need to add the U+FEFF (BOM) character when design a font

Tags: fonts, byte-order-mark

When design a font, is it necessary to add the U+FEFF (BOM) character? In some fonts it's left as an empty glyph.

Answer (score 1):

In past `U+FEFF` was (on very old Unicode versions) a zero width space, and it could come in middle of text. Now this should be used only as BOM, and it should be only used as first code point.

So it is up to you: do you want to handle very old Unicode as expected, or you want to show user it as wrong character?

I'm not aware of practical cases where you see the difference (first people to use Unicode were also much prone to upgrade data, people who tend to use old code probably upgraded later (BOM time) to Unicode).